# "attach" a python module similar to R?

Tags: python, import, module

In Python, when we import something:

```
import Module
```

when we later want to use functions created in the module we have to say

```
Module.foo()
```

Is there any way to "attach" the module so that if I simply call

```
foo()
```

It knows that I mean to use the foo defined in Module, as long as the name does not conflict with any name in the current file?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`from Module import *`

This imports all symbols in Module unless overriden by `__all__`.

You can also explicitly import (which is better) only the symbols you actually need.

`from Module import foo`

It's typically preferred to use the later. Even better is to use the module as namespacing. There's nothing wrong with `Module.foo()` vs. `foo()`. Once your program gets fairly large, this will help you quite a bit with refactoring.

Answer (score 1):

You can just do `from module import foo`, and then refer to `foo()` directly.