# Equivalent of R's "attach"ing a dataframe in Python?

Tags: python-3.x, pandas

I saw a [similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/30549759/5411606) on OS but that one is different as it relates to functions and not dateframes.

Imagine we have a dataframe `df` with a column `x`. In R, if you "attach" `df`, then you can directly use `x` for example in `print(x)`, without having to reference `df` as in `print(df['x'])`. Is there any equivalent in Python?

Comment: What problem are you trying to solve by writing `print(x)` instead of `print(df['x'])` or `print(df.x)`?

Comment: Coding arsimony and saving time. I'm constantly performing algebraic operations on 100s of columns this df has.

Comment: All you save is typing `df.`. It does not sound worth polluting the namespace. And the short answer to your question is _no, there is not_.

Comment: Nope. I am working with many dataframes with hundreds of columns and several hundreds of lines of codes constantly referencing the long data frame names and their many columns. I wish it were just one dataframe with a short name like `df`.

Comment: Nope. I am working with many dataframes with hundreds of columns and several hundreds of lines of codes constantly referencing the long data frame names and their many columns. I wish it were just one dataframe with a short name like `df`.

Comment: Why not rename the dataframes? The use of long variable names is discouraged, anyway.

Comment: you can separate chunks of work into functions that accept a dataframe named `df`. within the function refer to `df` & call the function with your descriptively named dataframe as an argument.

Comment: @HaleemurAli I see your point, thanks. This would be my second best option. But there must be a better way. This is NOT the case of importing functions into the name space and the chances of functions with similar names from different packages getting all mixed up. This is the case of importing columns (series) of data with totally unique names into the name space.

Comment: I knew that we can call R packages from python using [rpy2](http://rpy2.readthedocs.io/en/version_2.8.x/introduction.html) module. Give a try on this.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

First, the caveat that you *should not do this*. That said, you can set global variables via a loop across the columns:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'a': [1,2,3], 'b': [4,5,6], 'c': [7,8,9]})

for col in df.columns:
    globals()[col] = df[col]

>>> a
0    1
1    2
3    3
```

If you wanted it to be something you use regularly, perhaps you write a function (again, I strongly discourage this):

```
def attach(df):
    for col in df.columns:
        globals()[col] = df[col]

df = pd.DataFrame({'a': [1,2,3], 'b': [4,5,6], 'c': [7,8,9]})
attach(df)
```

Comment: Exactly what I needed. Thanks. If a column's name is, say, `Series`, then I understand why you are discouraging this practice as that `Series` may be mixed up with, say, Panda's Series. But if all column names are unique, say such as `GDP2018Q2', or `USD_spot`, and thus no chances of getting mixed up with anything else, would you still be concerned about anything?

Comment: I would be concerned about setting global names dynamically without some robust checks on existing names and built-ins, and on the column names to be used. Generally, I think hacking namespaces like this can lead to unintended consequences. But it's your program, so if you are sure of your inputs and if this works as you desire, then go for it.

Answer (score 0):

This sounds like aliasing

```
x = df.x  #alias x as df.x
df.x = 10 #change df.x

print(x) #prints out series df.x, which is now all 10s
```